# How to make LAN server to Public what installed in virtualbox (ubuntu with briged network)?

Tags: server, virtualbox, public, lan

I searched so much, read a lot of forum posts but I've still not got a solution for how to make my server to public what is in Virtualbox.

1. My router (netis WF2411), there I guess I enabled everything.
2. I use Xubuntu like desktop operating system
3. Virtualbox is the latest and I installed Ubuntu 12.04 amd64 server to it with Bridged network mode
4. I can access server from lan (server ip is 192.168.1.6 from lan) - lamp installed and work
5. I can't access this Virtualbox server with public ip (also tried install no-ip duc with shadowvzs.ddns.net domain name) - if I try to access it, it make a long loading then Chrome says it can't reach the site.

Mainly use 80/8080 and 29000 ports (lamp/tomcat/pw server)

Does anybody have a good idea how to make it a public server from lan server?

Comment: Very dangerous. Strongly suggest you research "demilitarized zone" properly and make sure you understand what is going on before leaving your server running exposed to internet for more than a few seconds. Also don't do it without ensuring you have patched all possible vulnerabilities of your LAMP setup, your server, your local network and all clients attached to it. The danger is that your data will be hacked quicker than you can say "Oh dear, where did all my data go?" Alternatively, buy some cheap LAMP hosting and at least it would only be the data in the hosting server which is at risk.

Comment: i want open just these ports for game what is only while i play, the mysql and game is in vbox, so basically if the game is hacked isn't big deal because not for commercial or something, i just want play with few friend, but if i understand well they can't do too much problem on my main system just in virtualbox server, no?

Answer (score 0):

i used this command

```
dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
```

and its showed different ip then no-ip.com what kinda weird because on site its noticed the duc is active in vbox server and work :/

so i also disabled firewall (https://askubuntu.com/questions/250775/how-do-i-turn-off-the-firewall-in-ubuntu-12-04) and setted DMZ on router and with new ip everything work well